# Google Cloud SQL - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, sql, azure, cloud

I have a site remotely hosted away from the Google Cloud SQL instance. I have set up and authorised CIDR range for this. I am using PHP (PDO) to connect to the Google Cloud SQL instance with an application built on the Laravel 5 framework. The website itself is deployed on Windows Azure, I do not have a choice about this stack.

My problem is on probably about 10% of page loads I receive the error:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`

While trying to set up the CIDR for this in the developer console (getting my Azure IP and converting it to a range) I had this problem 100% of the time, so it's possible that it's related to IP authorisation, however why would this work 80-90% of the time, and deny the application sporadically?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely timeouts.

Comment: Do you check for the limits of the platform? You may be using more resources than you are allowed to?

Comment: @mkaatman Page loads are generally very fast from http request, to sql, back, to the final http response, under 1 second every time, so I think timeouts are unlikely?

Comment: @frankish I have a test staging area with a very similar setup (also Azure) that connects to the exact same Google Cloud SQL instance, and I haven't had the error from this website - which leads me to believe it could be authorisation related?

Comment: Is your Azure IP static? Maybe it changes because of automatic load balancing?

Comment: @frankish I have just set it to allow 0.0.0.0/0 (any IP addresses), and still get the problem sporadically, perhaps it isn't related to the allowed IP range.

Comment: Did you try switching the Cloud SQL settings to "Always On" from "On Demand"? I would also say check the app id you use, but you say that it %80-%90 works.

Comment: @frankish I've set to Always On, tried for 15 minutes. Same issues. Perhaps the problem is with the Azure configuration (as my staging area works fine, also Azure, but slightly different configuration - for example it is free tier).

Comment: You probably need to revisit your design. Latency alone between the two clouds is likely to cause transient failures, let alone allowing anyone (0.0.0.0/0) on the internet to port scan and potentially hack your MySQL DB (good luck if GCP doesn't come along and clobber your setup for that).

Comment: @SimonW I allowed 0.0.0.0/0 just to check if it was authentication related. I'm aware that the design of the system isn't ideal, I also stated that I do not have a choice about the stack. Your point doesn't explain why one Azure website would work and the other would not.

Comment: Jamie try to put a "time elapsed" check to your code and print it on the screen or at least hide it in the html code. Check that value when you get "Mysql gone away" to see if the "time elapsed" value is over the average "time elapsed" value.

Comment: Are you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

go to the cloud sql instance you created. Under properties you will see "authorized applications" click manage and add the project id of your project to it. hope that works for you

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case someone else ran into similar problems like I did, this might help...

- Check your system clock, make sure it's not behind (happened to me with a local docker instance)
- Check your credentials to make sure they're correct and match up with the instance you're trying to connect to.

Good luck